# How do I skip the default print dialog for a print() call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing, zpl

I'm building an application where the user will frequently print barcodes to a zebra GK420d label printer. I want to avoid the default print dialog where the user has to accept the printer settings every time they want to print a label.
The goal is to send the print instructions (ZPL) to the client application and have the client device send these instructions to the zebra printer.
All printers will have a static ip address that will be saved in a database and linked to a specific workspace.

Comment: Try https://blog.kiosksimple.com/2015/04/30/how-to-print-in-javascript-without-displaying-the-print-dialog-box/#:~:text=TO%20YOU%20WEBSITE.-,How%20to%20Print%20in%20JavaScript%20Without%20Displaying%20the%20Print%20Dialog,print()%3B%20and%20that's%20it! (not very flexible)

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more flexible. It would be unfortunate to have to force restrictions upon clients for such a small issue.
@JackBashford Thanks though!

Comment: If the printers have the optional ZebraNet PrintServer installed, you can use `XMLHttpRequest` to POST the ZPL directly to the printer, bypassing the browser's built-in print functionality entirely.

Comment: @MarkWarren Hi Mark, I'm using the GK420d. It has a simple web server installed. The server responds with a 200 OK but I'm unable to testprint :( this is my test request: `curl -v -d '^XA^FO70,50^BY6^BCN,150,Y,N,N,A^FD12345678^FS^XZ' http://192.168.18.80:9100/pstprnt `
Output: 
*   Trying 192.168.18.80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.18.80 (192.168.18.80) port 9100 (#0)
> POST /pstprnt HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.18.80:9100
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 43 out of 43 bytes

Comment: Two things:  1) The POST goes to port 80, not 9100.  And 2) when using curl, you want the data posted as text/plain.  Try:  `curl -v -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d '^XA^FO70,50^BY6^BCN,150,Y,N,N,A^FD12345678^FS^XZ' http://192.168.18.80/pstprnt`

Comment: You were right, I also noticed this a few hours after I posted this :-) 
Now I have  the issue that my ASP.NET CORE 3 application does not allow CORS, since it is HTTPS and the printer is HTTP :(
I will make a seperate post about this :-)